# How to run OS-agnostic Jest test files that check paths?

Tags: node.js, windows, jestjs

Let's say I have the following:

```
expect(func).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/path/to/file');
```

This would work fine on NIX operating systems. However, this test would fail on Windows platform because I should instead have

```
expect(func).toHaveBeenCalledWith('\path\to\file');
```

What's the best way to write tests so they are OS agnostic? I was looking at this [article](https://medium.com/doctolib/how-to-run-the-same-jest-test-suite-across-several-platforms-jest-os-detection-plugin-included-f8113832482b) but that is basically saying write different tests for different OSes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can *extend `expect`* to add the matching behaviour you want, there are lots of examples in [`jest-extended`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended). For this case, perhaps using the tools available in [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) to test against the appropriate path for whatever OS the tests are running on:

```js
import { matcherHint, printExpected, printReceived } from "jest-matcher-utils";
import * as path from "path";

expect.extend({
    toMatchPath: (actual, expected) => {
        const normalised = path.join(...expected.split("/"));
        return actual === normalised
            ? { pass: true, message: passMessage(actual, normalised) }
            : { pass: false, message: failMessage(actual, normalised) };
    },
});

const passMessage = (actual, expected) => () => `${matcherHint(".not.toMatchPath")}

Expected value not to match:
  ${printExpected(expected)}
Received:
  ${printReceived(actual)}`;

const failMessage = (actual, expected) => () => `${matcherHint(".toMatchPath")}

Expected value to match:
  ${printExpected(expected)}
Received:
  ${printReceived(actual)}`;
```

In your tests you then *always* write POSIX-style paths `/path/to/thing`, and `path` takes care of providing the appropriate path separator for the current OS. In use:

```js
describe("path matching", () => {
    const actual = path.join("path", "to", "thing");

    it("normalises paths for matching", () => {
        expect(actual).toMatchPath("path/to/thing");
    });

    it("can be negated", () => {
        expect(actual).not.toMatchPath("path/to/other/thing");
    });

    it("can be used asymmetrically", () => {
        const fn = jest.fn();
        fn(actual);
        expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.toMatchPath("path/to/thing"));
    });

    it("fails usefully", () => {
        const fn = jest.fn();
        fn(actual);
        expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.not.toMatchPath("path/to/thing"));
    });
});
```

Output:

```
  path matching
    ✓ normalises paths for matching (3 ms)
    ✓ can be negated
    ✓ can be used asymmetrically (2 ms)
    ✕ fails usefully (3 ms)

  ● path matching › fails usefully

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: not.toMatchPath<path/to/thing>
    Received: "path/to/thing"

    Number of calls: 1

      44 |              const fn = jest.fn();
      45 |              fn(actual);
    > 46 |              expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.not.toMatchPath("path/to/thing"));
         |                         ^
      47 |      });
      48 | });

      at Object.toHaveBeenCalledWith (server/demo.test.js:46:14)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 3 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
```

Comment: This was wonderful. Quick thing: this fails when calling with `toHaveBeenNthCalledWith` what's the reason?

Comment: @Kousha could you expand on "fails"? Replacing `expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.toMatchPath("path/to/thing"));` with `expect(fn).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, expect.toMatchPath("path/to/thing"));` works fine locally.

Comment: Yes sorry you are absolutely right - I had some issues with the trailing `/` that was causing this issue. Thank you for your help