# Jest Array Assertion: ANY in expected are in actual

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Say I am using Jest to make an assertion on two arrays of the same type, call them `actual` and `expected`. Using the `arrayContaining` matcher, it is simple to test that ALL elements in `expected` are in `actual`:

```js
test('ALL elements in expected are in actual', () => {
    const actual = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    const willPass = [2, 3, 4]
    const willFail = [5, 6, 7]

    expect(actual).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(willPass))
    expect(actual).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(willFail))
});
```

And the inverse, that ANY in `expected` is NOT in `actual`, just needs the `not` modifier.

However, I can't seem to find the right way to use this matcher for the scenario "ANY in expected are in actual". Of course, I could use a raw JS evaluation to create an assertion:

```js
expect(willPass.some(v => actual.includes(v))).toBe(true)
```

But doing this means that the resultant failure message is very generic (expected true received false, not very helpful).

Is there a way to test that ANY element in `expected` is in `actual` using Jest's matchers?

Comment: `jest-extended` is linked from the top of https://jestjs.io/docs/expect: https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toincludeanymembersmembers

Comment: In general, if you want matching that isn't supported elsewhere, you can extend `expect` yourself as I show in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67332826/3001761.

Comment: Ah, I see that I completely missed the sentence suggesting jest-extended in the docs! Thanks for pointing that out, it seems to have what I'm looking for: https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toincludeanymembersmembers

Answer (score 0):

As jonrsharpe pointed out in a comment, while Jest does not have a native assertion for the ANY case, the community maintains a library called [jest-extended](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended), which has an assertion called [toIncludeAnyMembers](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toincludeanymembersmembers).